# Maintaining service in an android application

Tags: java, android, service, android-service-binding

I am quite new to android development and I have started making a music player. I have two activities. One is the main that you can see all the albums in the local storage and select one. Upon selecting one a second activity launches that displays the songs from that album. The user can tap on a song and the song plays. I have binded a service to that activity and the song is playing. However when the song starts playing I can not navigate to the previous activity.

I would like to be able to return to the main activity and be able to keep browsing albums and picking another song. I am not sure if I have to bind the service again and how to do it.

Here are some segments of the code.

Manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AlbumActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SongActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="realm.chaos.mplayer.AlbumActivity" />
    </activity>
    <service android:name="realm.chaos.mplayer.MusicService"/>
```

And here is the part in the SongActivity that I define and use the musicService.

```
private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        musicSrv.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

I do not know if that is of help but to play songs I extend the default media controller of Android. I plan to change that in the future since it seems buggy and I am not happy with its functionality.
My code is based on this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778. My SongActivity is actually the activity described there and the AlbumActivity is a new activity that I use as parent.

*** Also I have read that you can either bind or start a service. I am not sure which one is suggested. I want to leave the music playing and do change views. Probably I will add more views that might be used to update the service.

Comment: actually need more information.!

Comment: What would you like to see? I can provide all my code but the code is heavily based on this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778. I would appreciate even some theoretical information. Like I if you bind a service to a view how can you change activities and keep the service running.